# POM file Uploaded by Artifactory Jenkins plugin won't resolve in Maven builds

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory

I am building a jar in Jenkins and uploading it to an Artifactory repository. I've verified the jar, the pom, and the hash files are present in the repository. When I try to build a project on my machine that has a dependency on the jar, it downloads the jar correctly but then I get a POM file is missing message and the maven build fails. I don't see any rhyme or reason why this should fail, I've done an Artifactory trace on the jar and the pom in Chrome and Firefox and the response says that it found the files. So I don't understand what could bve causing the issue? We were running Artifactory 5.2.1 and upgraded over the weekend to 5.5.1, but it hasn't changed anything. What should I be looking at?

Thanks.

EDIT: This question is about to be moot. Discussions are in progress about setting up a generic maven repository and avoiding the use of Artifactory altogether, since it won't do what is needed.

Comment: Can you provide the corresponding request.log of the Artifactory server?
Look for a 404 in there, and check that the URL is the same as what you tested in Chrome / Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved. Turned out to be a Maven problem, not an Artifactory problem. Our maven settings contain a proxy setting so we can pull down jar from Maven Central - problem was, our company url was incorrectly configured in the nonProxyHosts tag, was set to domain.org, instead of *.domain.org, so it was trying to retrieve the maven artifact through the proxy instead of going directly to the Artifactory server. My apologies to the Artifactory devs for blaming the problem on Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your groupId and artifactId are correct.  I've lost a lot of time thinking it's a maven problem when it's really just that I reversed a couple letters in a long groupId.

Next, have you tried 'forcing' maven to bypass its local cache?  Try running `mvn -U <your tasks>`

If that doesn't work, try deleting the `~/.m2/repository/path/to/the/artifact/with/the/missing/pom` and use `mvn -U` again

Comment: Tried all of those things with no success.